# Why isn't my collision detection working properly in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to implement collision detection in pygame. It works perfectly when I run into a wall from the x-direction (left and right). Unfortunately, it does not work when I run into the wall from the y-direction (from above and below).Whenever the player runs into the wall from the y-direction it gets stuck. I have looked around for similar questions on Google and stackoverflow, but I did not find a satisfying answer.

### My code:

```
import pygame
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        change_x = 0
        change_y = 0
        def __init__(self,x,y):
                pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self) 
                self.image = pygame.image.load("Cool_guy.png").convert()
                self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
                self.rect.x = x
                self.rect.y = y

        def changespeed(self,x,y):
                self.change_x+=x
                self.change_y+=y


        def update(self,walls):
                #updates location of x coordinate
                old_x = self.rect.x
                new_x = self.change_x + old_x
                self.rect.x = new_x
                collide = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self,walls,False)
                if collide:
                        #Hit a wall go back to old position
                        self.rect.x = old_x
                #updates location of y coordinate
                old_y = self.rect.y
                new_y =  self.change_y+old_y
                self.rect.y = new_y
                if collide:
                        #hit a wall go back to old positon
                        self.rect.y = old_y
```

This code above is just my Player class, because I suspect that the problem is in this class (probably my update function). I will edit the question, if you need more code. I am using Python 3.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be easier and maybe even fix your code if you took care of the x and y both at once:

```
def update(self,walls):
    old_x = self.rect.x
    new_x = self.change_x + old_x
    old_y = self.rect.y
    new_y = self.change_y + old_y
    self.rect.x = new_x
    self.rect.y = new_y
    collide = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self,walls,False)
    if collide:
            #Hit a wall go back to old position
            self.rect.x = old_x
            self.rect.y = old_y
    #updates location of x and y coordinates
```